# Word in the grid

Tags: word

A word has been hidden in this grid. The word will reveal where Bob's will is.

```
 M O P B V
 P B Y T K
 O Z R M V
 K Z F J F
 A Y S J H
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Many of the letters in the grid show up twice. If you only look at the ones that show up once, you find AHRST. Rearranging these gives TRASH. I feel bad for the executor of the will.

Comment: Yeah, me too, but on the upside the relatives can go dumpster diving :)